# Opencv UDP server client

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having problem to run the code, in server class int result = client->sendData((char*)(&buff[0]), buff.size());

I'm using vc2010, opencv 249

buff is undefined!

---server class ---

```
    char *addr = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 9999;

    int main(){
        cout<<"=== VIDEO SENDER ==="<<endl;
        //setup UDP client:
        UDPClient *client = new UDPClient(addr, port);
        //setup openCV
        cvNamedWindow("UDP Video Sender", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
        if(!capture){
            cout<<"No camera found."<<endl;
            goto DONE;
        }
        IplImage *frame;
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        IplImage *small = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width / 2, frame->height / 2),
            frame->depth, 3);

    while(1){
        //capture frame and resize
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvResize(frame, small, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        cvShowImage("UDP Video Sender", small);
        //send
        int result = client->sendData((char*)(&buff[0]), buff.size());
        if(result < 0)
            cout<<"Failed to send."<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"Sent a frame of size "<<result<<endl;

        cvWaitKey(15);
    }
    goto DONE;

DONE:
    cout<<"Press any key to continue."<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I don't see `buff` defined anywhere in your code.  The error message you provided is accurate.  Not sure what else you'd be looking for.

Comment: please, opencv's c-api died in 2010. don't live under a rock.

Comment: @berak,I wonder if opencv C-api is still faster than opencv c++-api!

Comment: whatever left of the c-api is mostly a wrapper around c++ functionality nowadays. so definitely not faster.

Comment: besides, your poor usage of the c-api is causing a memleak, you never release the 'small' one

Answer (score 1):

well, the message is clear you should define your buffer. :)

Try to define you buffer then add this line before sending:

// copy image data to your buffer
`std::memcpy(pointer to your buffer , frame->imageData, buffer size);`

Comment: hi, I have done,  char* buff;  std::memcpy(buff, frame->imageData, sizeof(frame->imageData));  i still get runtime error define buff